# Форматирование std::string или QString в C++

Tags: c++, qt

Нужна помощь с обработкой аргументами std::string строки.

На вход поступает string или QString переменная с сырыми модификаторами внутри, к примеру:
std::string s = "I have %d apples, my mother have %f apples"

Вместе с строкой поступает массив аргументов, которые должны быть в нее вставлены, к примеру:
long l[2] = {1,0};
Количество аргументов в строке может быть разное, значения всех аргументов и их количество нам известно.

Каким способом можно преобразовать string строку, зная заранее количество аргументов и их значения? Обработка должна идти так, как будто это работает snprintf, только в него мы передаем все время разное кол-во аргументов и строку в виде переменной string

По примеру выше, должно быть на выходе std::string s = "I have 1 apples, my mother have 0 apples"

Comment: А `sprintf/vsprintf` не поможет?

Comment: Проблема в том что vsprintf, как я понимаю, принимает либо один аргумент, либо va_list аргументов. У меня сгенерировать va_list аргументов не получалось, на выходе что-то не то постоянно получалось. Возможно просто я криворук

Comment: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в том, что вы скинули, методы не умеют принимать в себя строку как переменную string? Просто если смотреть по документациям, в первом случае везде строка прописывается полностью в кавычках, во втором случае используется C++20, как я понял, а я пытаюсь найти вариант под C++11

Comment: @tocic Беда в том, что там модификаторы не те, что в `printf` и которые используются судя по вопросу...

Comment: Кстати! если у вас массив аргументов — т.е. они *одного типа*, то у вас в строке должны быть все модификаторы одинаковые?

Comment: Модификаторы, как мне объясняли, будут использовать все printf-овские, а аргументы я храню в long векторе, т.к. 8 байт достаточно чтобы хранить все аргументы (string и char не передаются). Я пробовал через цикл пробежать по vsprintf-у, передавая каждый элемент вектора, но в таком случае vsprintf сразу же обрабатывал все входящие модификаторы, используя только переданную одну переменную, и на второй проход цикла он получал уже якобы "готовую" строку. Дико извиняюсь если что-то плохо объясняю

Comment: Если число аргументов ограничено, можно просто передать больше аргументов, чем используется: https://godbolt.org/z/rGc6Y9fGo

Answer (score 0):

Можно замутить через Parameter packs

Пример:

```
QString strArgs(const QString &str)
{
    return str;
}

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
QString strArgs(const QString &str, T value, Targs... args)
{
    QString returnVal = str.arg(value);
    return strArgs(returnVal, args...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString str = "%1, %2, %3, %4";
    qDebug()<<strArgs(str, 1, 2, 3,4);;
    qDebug()<<strArgs(str, "w", 1, 2,"k");
}
```

Comment: Окей, я попробую, спасибо большое. Пока что временно запилил костыльный вариант, как попробую ваш - отпишусь)